# Is there a way to "cut" and "paste" parts of a string in PHP

Tags: php

I want to remove the first character of a string like so,

```
$a1 = "A10";
$a2 = substr($a1,1,strlen($startsem1)-1);
```

but I want to retrieve that removed "A" later on. Is there a way I can "cut" or "copy" that removed "A" to some variable?

Comment: why aren't you just splitting the string?

Comment: I'm going to be choosing from a pull down list of several different strings such as "A07", "A08", "A09", "A10", which are pulled from a database. I will need just the number at one point, but I will need the "A" later.

Comment: DarkXphenomenon, please specify "splitting the string" in PHP. There are numerous functions to "split" a string and I find none suitable for this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you mean:

```
$a1 = "A10";
$a2 = substr($a1,1,strlen($a1)-1);
echo $a1[0]; // output "A" eg old value for you
echo $a2; // output "10"
```

PHP supports array like syntax for strings too so `$a1[0]` (zero based index as in array) extracts first letter from string.

Answer (score 4):

Use `substr` again.

```
$a3 = substr($a1, 0, 1);
```

or as others commented, just [split the string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) on whatever delimiter you're interested in using.

Comment: I can't do it this way, because I'm going to be cutting A's, B's, and C's. And I need the A10 later on.

Answer (score 2):

You can do directly this way:-

```
<?php
$result1 = "A10";
$result2 = $result1{0};
echo "$result1{0} : " . $result1{0} . "\n";
echo "$result2 : " . $result2 . "\n";
?>
```

### Result:

```
A10{0} : A
A : A
```

Refer **[LIVE DEMO](http://codepad.org/sByfcmRh)**

Answer (score 1):

For fun, you could do this:

```
$a1 = "A10";
$split = str_split( $a1); // Split the string into an array
$first_char = array_shift( $split);
$everything_else = implode( '', $split);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can save it in its own variable (here I use string indexing to get the first character, but you may just as well use `substr`):

```
$saved_a = $a1[0];
```

Also note that you may skip the third parameter to substr if you want to get the rest of the string:

```
$a2 = substr($a1, 1);
```